# FirebaseCrashlytics initialise is not a function error

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4, crashlytics, ionic-native

When we are using the ionic native plugin in firebase-crashlytics for firebase crash report in our ionic app. It give the error that is "Object(...) is not a function at FirebaseCrashlytics.initialise ".

I try to downgrade the plugin but same issue each time.we are now using the latest version of this plugin.

we are using the this.firebaseCrashlytics.initialise(); to initialize the Crashlytics.

to install the plugin in ionic native the below command is using "npm install @ionic-native/firebase-crashlytics "

Attaching the image of error also[image]

Comment: you have found a solution ?

Comment: no. we have leave it for now. As of our RND it is issue due to @ionic-native/core version will be same as firebase-crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

This is Chintan from Fabric/Firebase support. Ionic is not officially supported, though a community of Developers have been known to make it work.